# Visual Studio XSD files with DLLs for Web Projects

Tags: visual-studio, dll, web, xsd

I'm trying to create a DLL using a Dataset.XSD file to access my website's VistaDB database.  The DLL develops and builds fine but I need to build the DLL once and then change the "path" of the database in the all the Website projects that finally references the dll (different databases and therefor database paths for each website that references the dll in it's bin folder).

I can't get the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString("myconstr").ConnectionString to stay in my DLL project.  As soon as I save it - it reverts back to whatever the Dataset.XSD file wants it to be (the database connectionstring that I developed it against).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if I just open it up in notepad, make the changes, and then build it works like it should.  It's kind of a pain in the butt to do this every time I make a changes to the XSD file though but it's better than nothing, I guess.